# Transgenderism and personality

Tags: personality, gender, big-five, transgender

**Has any research been conducted to study how individuals may vary on personality inventories, for example, the [Big Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits), based on whether they are cisgender versus transgender?**

Broadly, inquiry may divide into the following two domains:

1. Within a binary gender category, for example, female, do individuals  tend to score differently based on whether they were assigned female versus male sex at birth?
2. Among men and women combined, do transgender individuals, compared to cisgender, exhibit different personality trends?

It has been suggested at times  in  vernacular contexts that transgender individuals have greater [openness to new experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openness_to_experience), and this notion seems to have acquired some  momentum in political spheres, though  evidence supporting the claim is not generally provided.

Comment: check ["big five personality traits and gender"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&qsp=2&q=big+five+personality+traits+and+gender&qst=br) research titles.

there are visible papers which seem to be highly cited and probably related, e.g
[Gender differences in personality across the ten aspects of the Big Five](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2011.00178/full)
[Big Five Personality Traits as the Predictors of Creative Self-Efficacy and Creative Personal Identity: Does Gender Matter?](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jocb.32)

Comment: @ayvtill, The question concerns transgenderism, not gender broadly.